# Overriding joomla core email template

Tags: php, html, css, html-email, joomla3.0

Is there a way I can override the core email template that the admin will received once a guest sent message on contact form?

I would like to customize the look and feel of the received email. At least I can include a email header and footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easy override like in joomla layouts and templates is not possible. If you want to modify your emails, you can...

1. change **language files** or make **language overrides** to modify your email (not what you´re looking for)
2. write your own **system plugin** which modifies your email methods. The email methods are stored in `/libraries/joomla/mail/mail.php`. Here you can wrap a template around your content.
3. use a **extension** which catches your templates and wraps them into templates like [joomla email beautifier](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/email-beautifier/).

I´m with you, hope in the future there will be an easy native option to override mail templates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have checked the /libraries/joomla/mail/mail.php file , however, I'm quite unfamiliar with it. I want to achieve is to add html and css that when someone receives it, it looks nice. Is there any other way aside from purchasing module like email beautiful?

Comment: I think your only chance is to hook in with a plugin. You can´t easily override the file because after next joomla update, your changes will be lost.

Comment: Thanks! I'll find a free email template like the emailbeautifier. If you can recommend one, I'll consider it.